# vector addition using graphical and component method

Tags: vectors, physics

Suppose there are four vectors A = 8.00 cm, South; B = 15.0 cm, 30.0° E◦N; C = 12.0 cm, 25° S◦W; and D = 10.0 cm, 53° W◦N. Using the materials, employ the graphical method (tail-to-tip) to determine the resultant vector A+B+C+D. Compare your results when using component method

i tried graphing it but i think my graph is wrong, my angle and resultant vector is way off compared to my answer when using component method
[image]

Comment: Please add symbols for $A,B,C,D$, mark the directions, and put labels for the angles.